# Implementando una operacion matematica y el resultado me lanza [Error] stray '\226' in program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

main() { 

    double  x = 7 + 1 * (4 * ( 5 - ( 9 + 3 ) / 6 ) ) ;

    cout << "el resultado de x es: " <<x;

    getch();    

}
```

Comment: Reescribe el codigo, con tu teclado, desde cero, probablemente contiene caracteres que no son validos en un programa de C++.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado **( entradas y salidas por ejemplo )**, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te han comentado el carácter para la resta es incorrecto. El signo menos que tu usas se corresponde al valor 226 en octal o 96 en hexadecimal del código ASCII extendido. El signo menos debería ser el valor 2D en hexadecimal (55 en octal). Aunque ambos muestren lo mismo al imprimirlos en la mayoría de editores, el compilador no piensa lo mismo.

Este error es muy común cuando se copia y pega código de documentos procedentes de editores de texto como Word.

Por otro lado, no se que te habrán dicho pero si quieres seguir el estándar de c++ la función `main()` **debe retornar siempre un entero**. Puedes mirar la documentación oficial al respecto [aquí](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

El código quedará así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 7 + 1 * (4 * ( 5 - ( 9 + 3 ) / 6 ) ) ;
    cout << "el resultado de x es: " << x;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tiene tu implementacion es que hay un caracter no valido. Parece que es el correcto, pero debes cambiarlo. Me refiero al signo '-' en la operacion.

Comment: gracias isaac es completamente acertada tu respuesta solucione el problema

Comment: Marca la respuesta como la aceptada para que los otros users sepan que ya está la respuesta que se estaba buscando.

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu operación tiene un operador que no reconoce c++, en la parte "-" talves sea un guion

> ```
> Octal  = 226 
> Decimal= 2×8²+2×8¹+6×8⁰ = 150 
> Binary = 10010110 
> Hex    = 96
> ```

o talves tu resultado esta siendo interpretado como desconocido

Comment: gracias, solo era el signo menos tenia un guion.